# Java error getResource() after compilation into jar

Tags: java, linux, jar, getresource

Yesterday I finally finished my JavaFX application which perfectly ran in IDE, but when I tried to convert it to a `.jar` file and then run it... it didn't work. I found that my class can not import any `.fxml` file using `getClass().getResource()`. 
So I created a sample code which is trying to read text file `CheckFile.txt`.

Class path tree:

```sh
.
├── ClassFileTry.iml
├── out
│   ├── artifacts
│   │   └── ClassFileTry_jar
│   │       └── ClassFileTry.jar
│   └── production
│       └── ClassFileTry
│           ├── com
│           │   └── company
│           │       ├── CheckFile.txt
│           │       └── Main.class
│           └── META-INF
│               └── MANIFEST.MF
└── src
    ├── com
    │   └── company
    │       ├── CheckFile.txt
    │       └── Main.java
    └── META-INF
        └── MANIFEST.MF
```

Sample java code:

```java
public static void GetResource() {
    String result = null;
    String url = (Main.class.getResource("CheckFile.txt")).getPath();
    System.out.println("URL = " + url);

    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(url));
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = reader.nextLine();
            result = data;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output error:

```sh
$ java -jar ClassFileTry.jar
URL = file:/home/tucna/Desktop/ClassFileTry/out/artifacts/ClassFileTry_jar/ClassFileTry.jar!/com/company/CheckFile.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/tucna/Desktop/ClassFileTry/out/artifacts/ClassFileTry_jar/ClassFileTry.jar!/com/company/CheckFile.txt (No such file or directory.)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
    at com.company.Main.GetResource(Main.java:49)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
null
```

I am using Linux and IntelliJ with java 15.0.2  
**So my questions are:** What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Why does `getResourceAsStream()` for reading files work and `getResource()` does not?

I'll be very **grateful** for any help! **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Because the url does not refer to a file.

Comment: because `File` does not work with JAR (to access files inside JAR) - follow Kadakovs [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66423604/15244370)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.io.File` represents an actual file on disk. Your resource is *not* that; it's an entry in a jar file. `new File(someUrl)` is a non-starter. The go-to alternative is to never use file for thus stuff, instead, check the API you're using, it tends to have an alternative form that takes a `URL` or `InputStream`. So it is here, [Scanner can also take an InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)):

```
try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/CheckFile.txt")) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // do you magic here.
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could read your resource as stream. Try this:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try (InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/CheckFile.txt")) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append("\n");
            }
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "", ex);
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Reason for downvote: Bad exception handling, very bad resource handling.